# How do you update the file executable location targeted/searched by a GUI icon in the GUI-based Applications dock?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, appmenu

I had Google Chrome installed in a local folder, and it ran okay.

Then, I moved the folder to `/bin` because I wanted it more properly located on my system.

Now, the GUI shortcut in Applications doesn't work.

In fact, after a while, it went away.
Running Google Chrome through the terminal using `./usr/applications/google-chrome` works just fine. In fact, it boots very quickly, which is great.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, I moved the folder to /bin because I wanted it more properly
> located on my system.

You are misinformed: the folder `/bin` is **not** a more proper location on your system.

Folders under /opt would be appropriate. The executable then can be linked to `/usr/local/bin` to allow running the application by just typing the name of the executable.

> Running Google Chrome through the terminal using
> ./usr/applications/google-chrome works just fine.

This cannot just work "fine"  anytime because this is a relative path.

The command you indicate means: "run the binary 'google-chrome' that is located in a folder "applications", which in turn is in a folder "user" that exists in my *current* working directory. Thus, if you change your working directory, that command will not anymore work.

To allow executable to be started without having to type an entire pathname, place a link to the executable in one of the folders in your search PATH, i.e., `~/.local/bin` for binaries only the current user should access, or `/usr/local/bin` for binaries any user should access. Other folders include `/usr/bin` and `/bin` (actually just a symlink to the former, nowadays), but these are managed by the package management system. Stay out of these.

> How do you update the file executable location targeted/searched by a GUI icon in the GUI-based Applications dock?

The "GUI-based Applications dock" on disk exists as a small text file with a `.desktop` extension. Such file will produce an icon in the Applications overview provided 1) it is valid, i.e., it, among others, must refers to an existing executable on the system and 2) it is placed in a dedicated directory, i.e., `~/.local/share/applications` for a custom launcher only the current user should see, or `/usr/local/share/applications`. `/usr/local/applications` is where launchers live that have been installed using the package management system. Stay out of that.

**Specifically to Google Chroome**

Google Chrome offers a `.deb` installation package. This uses the package management system, so all is set up automatically for you. Moreover, it causes the program to automatically be updated. Prefer to use that approach rather than trying to install manually.

Comment: Thank you. That was a wonderful response.

Comment: When I double click on the .deb installer, it opens the app store and then says "Failed to install file: not supported". I think I can just unpack the .deb in termainal, ya?

Comment: Thank you again; I installed using dpkg -i and it seems to have automatically detected my /opt folder! There's an icon folder called google in the file browser with a lock on the corner, and the same folder in /usr/bin/google without a lock on it. I don't know what the lock means or why it's installed in two spots, but the gui-triggered icon clicking on it now works! As well as just "google-chrome" from terminal. Thanks! =)

Comment: Okay so the /opt/google folder I suspected was due to something else I did, a mistake. So I deleted it and everything still works fine. I think it was a copy I made for some reason.